# Jenkinsfile: Scope of Variables in Groovy

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I need to segregate Target Environment based on JobName... Any idea what I may be doing wrong:

Jenkinsfile

```
#!groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
node {
    def BUILD_NUMBER=env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def RUN_ARTIFACT_DIR="tests/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    def PACK_DIR="MyPackage${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    def SFDC_USERNAME
    def workspace = env.WORKSPACE
    def MY_JOB_NAME = env.JOB_NAME
    def SFDC_HOST = env.SFDC_HOST_DH_TEST
    println MY_JOB_NAME

    if (MY_JOB_NAME.contains("BV_SFDX_CI_PreINT_Validate")) {

        print "For PreInt"
        def HUB_ORG=env.HUB_ORG_DH_PI
        def JWT_KEY_CRED_ID = env.JWT_CRED_ID_DH_PI
        def CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY=env.CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY_DH_PI
        println JWT_KEY_CRED_ID

    }

    else {

        print "For Int"
        def HUB_ORG=env.HUB_ORG_DH_IN
        def JWT_KEY_CRED_ID = env.JWT_CRED_ID_DH_IN
        def CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY=env.CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY_DH_IN

    }

    println 'KEY IS' 
    println JWT_KEY_CRED_ID
    println HUB_ORG
    println SFDC_HOST
    println CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY
}
```

Error:

```
[Pipeline] echo
KEY IS
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JWT_KEY_CRED_ID for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:33)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor700.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help is appreciated as I am stuck for a long time over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the declaration `def JWT_KEY_CRED_ID` outside the blocks would eliminate the error e.g.:

```
def JWT_KEY_CRED_ID
if (MY_JOB_NAME.contains("BV_SFDX_CI_PreINT_Validate")) {
    JWT_KEY_CRED_ID = env.JWT_CRED_ID_DH_PI
    ...
}
else {
    JWT_KEY_CRED_ID = env.JWT_CRED_ID_DH_IN
    ...
}
println JWT_KEY_CRED_ID
```

Comment: Hello Keith,Thanks for your response... Yes I agree, but I am trying to setup different parameters based on the Job Name, but the param scope is getting limited to within the if else loop. :(

Comment: Hi @VarunSFDC, Not sure what you mean by "param scope"; can you add more detail to the question? Having all the `def` outside of the blocks and assigning one or the other value in the blocks looks appropriate here.

Comment: Hi Keith, I am trying to create a same Jenkinsfile to deploy develop branch on multiple Environments, Hence I am following such an approach where depending on the JobName, it will pick the Environment Configuration to deploy the Source Code to. Hence I have to declare it within the if-else

Comment: Hi Keith, I will try it and update you.

Comment: Hi Keith, That worked great... Will accept it as the correct ans. Many thanks